# Crash in application. RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, logcat

I got a crash on my application android.
logcat error:

```
07-09 12:00:46.486: D/dalvikvm(249): GC freed 613 objects / 50984 bytes in 89ms
07-09 12:00:49.944: D/dalvikvm(249): GC freed 2700 objects / 118760 bytes in 76ms
07-09 12:00:50.406: D/AndroidRuntime(249): Shutting down VM
07-09 12:00:50.406: W/dalvikvm(249): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-09 12:00:50.417: E/AndroidRuntime(249): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{allo.nascubetest/allo.nascubetest.MainActivity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at allo.nascubetest.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:111)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-09 12:00:50.444: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  ... 11 more
07-09 12:00:50.454: I/dalvikvm(249): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-09 12:00:50.554: I/dalvikvm(249): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-09 12:00:52.084: I/Process(249): Sending signal. PID: 249 SIG: 9
```

in my OnCreate:

```
    Intent thisIntent = getIntent();
    date = thisIntent.getExtras().getString("date");
```

and my line 111:

```
    labelDate.setText(date);
```

Comment: u are getting a null pointer exception at line: 111, please post your activity code.

Comment: pls provide code so that one can to know wat u hv done and wheres the mistake??there must be some initialization problem

Comment: What is there in **line number 111 of MainActivity2.java**?

Comment: The code you've posted is still too little to help you. You should post the entirety of your source for MainActivity2.java.

Comment: use `if(!date.length() == 0 || !date.equals(""))
{
labelDate.setText(date);
}` instead of `labelDate.setText(date);`
maybe this will stop `NullPointerException` but not solved your problem until you provide more code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accessing a null variable in line 111 in file MainActivity2.java .

Check what you wrote there.

From your code it seems that either labelDate is null or date is null.

Verify you have values in them , you can also debug.

In general, it seems best if you do some tutorial from developer.android.com .

Answer (score 0):

your date object is null in line 111, b'coz your intent may not have key named as date or the value will be null.

To prevent from this exception:

1. make sure that labelDate is not null
2. make sure that date object is not null before assign to setText();

ex:

```
if (date != null)
     labelDate.setText(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out with this code:

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle!=null){
String date=bundle.getString("date");
labelDate.setText(date);
}
```

hope this will help you.